# Using Dynamic SQL to ALTER Index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

Is it possible to rebuild an Index with the alter index statement via Dynamic SQL? If I change the @sqlStringSpatial variable which holds the query to a simple select statement with @i still as the parameter it works as intended but does not work with ALTER INDEX, is this possible?

```
DECLARE @sqlStringSpatial AS NVARCHAR(200) = N'ALTER INDEX @i ON dbo.test1910 REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = OFF)';
declare @dSQL as nvarchar(500) = N'@i nvarchar(50)';
DECLARE @indexName AS NVARCHAR(30) = N'Index01Tester';

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlStringSpatial, @dSQL, @i = @indexName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot parameterize `identifiers`

```
DECLARE @indexName AS NVARCHAR(30) = N'Index01Tester';

DECLARE @sqlStringSpatial AS NVARCHAR(200) = N'ALTER INDEX '+quotename(@indexName)+' ON dbo.test1910 REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = OFF)';

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlStringSpatial
```